# Visiting Japan and Doing Surveys Online

Tags: visas, japan, uk-citizens, work

I'm hoping to visit Japan in the next few years on holiday.  I would stay for almost the maximum tourism period, which for Uk Citizens is 3 months or so.  I have heard that law enforcement there is very strict indeed.  Evey day, I answer several online surveys that offer paymebts typically, and of up to £1.50 each or so.  It can sometimes be more, but only by a few pounds.  I do this all day long though, and as circumstances permits me.  Through various websites, I am able to be paid around £10-20 or just over per week for doing these, irregularly.  The payments can often be requested when I'm back home though.  I have travelled to Russia, USA and many other European countries, but I have never been questioned about doing it by any officials.

My question is, would I, or is there much likelihood to be found by law enforcement there, or if so, questioned or convicted for it as I would not have a working visa?  All of the surveys and market research I respond to are emailed to ne from companies online.  Mostly survey websites based in United Kingdom.  This is classed as self-employment usually.  I may be noticed as I often do this outdoors using a tablet device and in acoomodations too.

Comment: I know it may look like a petty matter, but it's best to be sure.  This has been treated more seriously on this before and not specifically about Japan by me.

Comment: Thanks.  My question is not duplicated there, and it is not the same things happening.  Mainly that I'm not employed by anybody else, and do those in a self-employed capscity and I'm a United Kingdom national, and not USA.   The answer may generally be the same, but it's not exact.  There are yes's and no's there, so if law enforcement officials question me, do they have enough cause for concern?

Comment: http://www.uk.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/index_000070.html  .as per here, we may lmo as much as I've do, but entry rules for my states for united Kingdom are far and different.  Not clear at all, and this clearly states that having an incorrect visa is not legal.